# How to determine if any file in a directory has changed

Tags: chef-infra

Is there a way for Chef to determine if it has changed any file in a given directory?  I'd like to restart a server process if any settings in a conf.d directory are updated.

I'm sure it's possible to write a list of md5sums to a file on each chef-client run, and compare current to previous iterations.  But that's a fair bit of code to address what seems to be a common scenario.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you aware of [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications)?

Comment: @StephenKing nope, that looks perfect.  If you submit that as an answer to the question, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Sorry for the delay (the notification was not delayed, only the spare time :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef provides a concept called [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications).

This allows you to define that a change in one resource triggers execution of another resource. The mentioned restart of a service after the config file changed is probably the most common use case.

```rb
template "/etc/foo/conf.d/example.conf" do
    notifies :restart, "service[foo]"
end

service "foo" do
    supports :restart => true, :reload => true
    action :enable
end
```

By default, notifications are `:delayed`, which means that they are triggered at the end of the Chef run. This helps you to avoid e.g. a service to restart once for every single changed configuration file. If you want an immediate notification, use

```rb
notifies :restart, "service[foo]", :immediately
```

Of course, you can use Chef's notifications not only for services, but for any resource. More examples are given in the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications).

Answer (score -2):

You can use inotifywait utility from the [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) package

Comment: Sorry, but chef is a configuration management system. The use of inotify would contradict to what at least I as a chef user want.